# parseFloat NaN issue

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in JavaScript which is holding a pound currency which is like

```
var a = £250
```

The value £250 is coming like this, its not directly assiged to a. its like 
var a = $("#spanid").text();

Now I am splitting this variable using `string.split` method like this

```
var b = a.split('£');
```

and when m checking with `alert(b[1])`, I am getting the value as 250 which is correct.

But now when m doing like this

```
var c = parseFloat(b[1]).
```

I am getting the value of C as `NaN`. I have tried so many things but I keep getting the value as `NaN`, can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Is the variable `a` a string?

Comment: I have declared variable a as VAR which is yes holding a string value

Comment: And JavaScript doesn't throw a syntax error on your code? There are no quotes around the monetary value ...

Comment: Btw, `parseFloat('£250'.split('£')[1]);` works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain the numerical pound value from the string `a` using a regular expression and ternary statement with a type conversion. This solution will work in obtaining the first monetary value mentioned in the string even if other characters are present before or afterwards. The result is also guaranteed to be a number, so it is safe to immediately use it in arithmetic calculations.

```
/* the first line is assumed */
var a = "£250";

var pounds = a.match(/[-.\d]+/g);
/* match possible parts of a pound */

pounds = pounds ? pounds[0] - 0 || 0 : 0;
/* convert match to an actual number type or else 0 if
 * no match is obtained or the match is not valid */
```

In some cases it may be important to know that a valid number was not present rather than assuming it is zero. If you would like to receive the `null` match or a possible `NaN` result from improperly formed numbers (like random mixtures of minus, decimal points, and digits), then you can replace the last statement with:

```
pounds = pounds ? pounds[0] - 0 : pounds;
```

Note: the regular expression above should not be used for extracting general numbers from nor validating arbitrary numbers within strings. It is only intended for very simple currency figures.

By the way, I provided an outstanding regular expression for extracting general numbers from strings a few months ago. I was going to link to it here for reference, but apparently the question where I answered it within has been deleted (probably it was a duplicate question so after I answered it, the question was deleted, as often happens). How do I go about finding my answers to questions that have been deleted?

Comment: I realize that my first draft was incomplete because I submitted it accidentally with an incomplete ternary statement while typing the explanatory comments within the code. (I'm using a new keyboard and its modifier keys are not in the normal places I'm used to.) Is there any other reason for the down vote which is still present in my answer now? This answer and technique I believe is more useful and a better general solution for people in the future who come to Stack Overflow looking for solutions to similar problems where it might not be exactly a matter of splitting at the `£` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is `a` not `string`:

```
var a = '£250';
var b = a.split('£');
var c = parseFloat(b[1]);
alert(c);
```

Update: OP was edited... Still does not have quotes around string though...

Comment: @vikashbhartia even that was a mistake in the question, this code is perfectly valid and works

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
var a = '£250',
    b = a.split('£'),
    c = parseFloat(b[1]);
alert(c);
```

`a` is a string so you need to wrap its value inside `' '` as well as using `a.split` instead of `string.split` since you have defined the variable name as `a`.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBEjZ/1/)**

Comment: HI felix, m doing the same way, it was a typo in my question where i gave string.split , it was a.split only.

Comment: Then it should works, check my demo in the answer :)

Comment: hi Felix, actually the first line where m storing £250 in variable a is like this var a = $("#spanid").text();